# coldfusion querynew() converts datetime to timestamp, annoyingly

Tags: coldfusion

If I run the query:

```
<cfquery name="gGet" datasource="#application.datasource#">
   select dateuploaded from table
</cfquery>
```

I get a lovely datetime as follows:

```
2012-12-01 12:46:00
```

But, if I create a new query object and insert the datetime into it

```
<cfset qReturn = queryNew("deployDate", "Date")>
<cfoutput query="qGet" startrow="1" maxrows="7">
    <cfset queryAddRow(qReturn)>
    <cfset querySetCell(qReturn,"deployDate",qGet.dateuploaded)>
</cfoutput>
```

I get this awful timestamp rubbish `{ts '2012-12-01 12:46:00'}`

What should I do to retain the datetime?

Alternatively, how would I re-format the timestamp into a datetime?

Comment: Are you using QueryNew()? If so it would be useful to have the code snippet that you wrote for that.

Comment: Sorry, I did have the code in there, but didn't put code tags around it.

Comment: You could use LSDateFormat() and LSTimeFormat() re introduce the formatting. You might have the change queryNew() to use a string. The problem with that is you would then have a string and not a date

Comment: what exactly is wrong with `{ts '2012-12-01 12:46:00'}`? what is it preventing you from doing?

Comment: It's complicated, but I'm throwing together a query object with data from different sources, database and xml. Later, I'm doing a query of queries, sorting by DeployDate and this is failing because the date formats aren't the same from the different sources. So...

Comment: I ended up just setting all dates as strings. The QofQ successfully sorts by date now.

Comment: That is a really awful solution to dealing with dates. Raise a new question to that effect to get some help with it.

Comment: I tend to agree that should not make a difference. Not as long as all of the input values are date objects. (Granted, QoQ can be quirky on occasion). But perhaps the problem is something else? Can you provide a small repo case that demonstrates the sorting problem?

Comment: I think the problem arose because of the xml input.  I don't think it would include any datetime objects.  The OP solved his problem by making everything a string.  Another option would have been to cast the xml inputs to timestamps.

Comment: Could be. That is why a repro case would help. Casting to a date/timestamp would be my preference. Treating dates as strings often leads to a whole different set of gotchas.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost certainly worrying about nothing. You're simply looking at what the date/time object returns when its `toString` method is called, which ColdFusion uses to be able to output something on the screen (which needs to be string data). The various values you are looking at will all be completely valid date/time types, just different classes implement `toString` differently. Your code will be dealing with the object, not the string representation of its value, so this is a non-issue.

Sounds like yer just outputting a raw value from either the DB result or the constructed query without formatting it, thus meaning CF needs to convert it to a string via its default `toString` method, and as I say above the `toString` methods vary from one DateTime implementation to another (the class of the object from the DB is different from the one CF uses for its own date objects, hence the different `toString` implementations you're seeing). One should never do that if one *cares* about what is being output, as you are here. Always convert a DateTime object to a string yourself if you care about the format used to display it:

`<cfoutput>#gGet.dateuploaded[1].dateTimeFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:nn:ss")#</cfoutput>`

`<cfoutput>#qReturn.deployDate[1].dateTimeFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:nn:ss")#</cfoutput>`

(respectively, based on the info you've provided us).

This will return & display the date object values in the format you specify, rather than leaving it to CF to use its defaults.

Only do this for *display*. For any date operations just leave the things as-is. You're only perceiving there to be something "wrong" here because you don't understand that dates in CFML are objects not just human-readable strings.  CF isn't - however - confused by this ;-)

I discuss this with more clarify (and taking up more space) in this [article about date/time objects and their string representations](http://adamcameroncoldfusion.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/what-you-see-is-not-necessarily-what.html), if you want to take a look.

Comment: I disagree.  I've had similar things happen to me.  I don't have access to any of my code right now but the scenario was something along the lines of doing a q of q with a db query and a cf QueryNew.  I was expecting one date to equal another and it didn't.  I can't remember how I solved it but this is not a non-issue.

Comment: Hence me saying "almost certainly", not "absolutely". On the basis of the info given and the question asked, this is *almost certainly* a case of worrying about nothing.

Comment: Q of Q is what makes this an issue. Ben Nadel blogs about a similar problem. http://www.bennadel.com/blog/399-ColdFusion-QueryNew-JavaCast-And-Date-Time-Values.htm

Comment: @user460114 from what I can tell from the lack of useful detail in Ben's article, he only had a problem there because he was mishmashing dates and strings: schoolkid error. Could well be what you were experiencing too, but nothing in your question suggests this was the situation. (I only revisit this 5yrs later cos someone just downvoted my answer, so I added some clarification, and spotted your follow-up comment. Hopefully my clarified answer might help someone in future).